A stylus app to take notes that can toggle erase mode with a pressed key
I'm looking for an app to take notes, which supports a stylus (e.g. OneNote, Evernote). The required feature is that I can toggle to erase mode by pressing a button.
Currently, I'm using on a PC (Windows) with a Wacom:
https://www.styluslabs.com/write/Help.html
I can write, and while shift is pressed, I erase.
What about an alternative:

An elaborate key combination that needs to be clicked each time to toggle erase on and off--I didn't find it convenient in powerpoint (e for erase, shift+p for pen, etc.)
Clicking a button on the pen--inconvenient.
Erase with a scribble--it's imprecise.

What's wrong with the app above? I look for something newer, which hopefully has current interface and features that I'm missing.
